# Django signals doesnt receive any signals (doesnt work)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Here is my code :

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
    from django.utils import timezone
    
    GENDER = (
        ("MALE", "Male"),
        ("FEMALE", "Female"),
    )


    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False):  # , **extra_fields
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have email address')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have username')

        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have password')

        # Normalize example: Test@gmail.com ---> test@gmail.com
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username,
                          date_joined=timezone.now())  # , **extra_fields
        user.is_staff = is_staff
        user.is_superuser = is_superuser

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    # Called when we run python manage.py createsuperuser
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, username, password,
                                is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
        return user


# Abstract Base User will give three fields by default (id, password, last_login)
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required to login
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELD is a list of the field names that will be prompted
    # for when creating a user via the createsuperuser management command
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='profile_pic/', default='profile_pic/user.png')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('RECEIVE')
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

installed apps on settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    'ckeditor',
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",

    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'pages_app.apps.PagesAppConfig',
    'vineyards.apps.VineyardsConfig',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'mailing.apps.MailingConfig',
]
```

I have read some information from here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYzTKcvO0Pk

I've also read some similar questions about django signals, but none of them are working

My django signals still doesn't work .. any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are extending django's user model then why to create another model for profile? you can just add the profile fields to the extended user model.

Comment: Your signals aren't working because you've defined a custom User model, while your signals are listening to Django's built-in User model. Please refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) on custom User classes, specifically read on setting the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and fetching the correct user model with `get_user_model()`.

Comment: @AjayLingayat I think it's recommended to have separate models and keep the extended custom user for only handle authentication things

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Yeahh that's solve my problem. We must use get_user_model() to fetch the correct user. Thanks!